# Derivative methods for artifical neural networks with single hidden layer

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to optimize the output of a given neural network with a single hidden layer.  To accomplish this, I intend to find solve for all combinations of inputs where the derivative of the neural network = 0 and select the input vector with the highest (or lowest, depending on the problem) neural network output.  It uses the activation function

$$
H_i,_j = \frac{1}{(1 + e^{-t})}
$$

where

$$
t = X_i\theta_j
$$

for a given input vector i and hidden node j.

The activation values of each hidden node are multiplied by a separate weight matrix to produce the outputs.  The output k of a given input vector i is the product of the hidden node activation values i and the weight vector k.

$$
O_i,_k = H_iW_k
$$

Could someone please explain the steps I would use to create the derivative formula for an input vector of arbitrary length, an arbitrary number of hidden nodes, a single hidden node layer, and a given output k?  Thank you so much.